# Python .format() parse ':' character

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I have the following code, the sql works fine in the database, but in python (using `.format()`) gives the error `': syntax error at or near ":"` so how do I parse the `:` character?

```
code = 'ABC:2674.45'
job = '103'

# connect to database
conn = connect()

# select query
query = """
    SELECT job, code  
    FROM schema.table
    WHERE job = {} and code = {} 
    order by code, job
""".format(job, code)

pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

Comment: When the query works in your database, do you use `code = ABC:2674.45` or `code = 'ABC:2674.45'`? You're asking python to create the former.

Comment: when querying the database the sql is hard coded, I use 'ABC:2674.45'

Comment: sql injection anybody? use parameters to your sql-command, not string format to create a string of the command you want to use

Comment: It is very well documented how to do this:   https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries 
 (Vers.2) or https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html  (Vers. 3)  - why ask here if you can research it within 15s ?!?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am turning it into a string first to use in the Pandas, command, so how do I avoid sql injection, I have spent more than '15s' looking into this so some constructive comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the issue, let me know if this can be improved

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT job, code FROM schema.table WHERE job = %s and code = %s order by code, job", con=conn, params=(pgram_job, sitecode))
```